# How to stop recording when using everyplay SDK?

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I'm new to Everyplay SDK, I'm using it with cocos2d v2.x for one of my old games, what I want to do is whenever I call the gameOver scene I want to stop the gameplay recording, but I cannot find a method that suggests that. 
There are a few delegate methods that get called when the recording stops.
I found there were methods that enable always recording mode and a time limited recording mode. But what I couldn't find was how to stop the recording and get the reply ready when a certain action gets called.

Answer (score 0):

Start recording with:

```
[[[Everyplay sharedInstance] capture] startRecording];
```

Stop recording with:

```
[[[Everyplay sharedInstance] capture] stopRecording];
```

Everyplay documentation: https://developers.everyplay.com/documentation

Comment: Thanks, earlier I was not looking into capture class, then I found these methods there.